# How to get raws where the data are bigger than the ancestor?

Tags: sqlite

I have sorted table according to *number* column as follows:

```
color - string
number - integer
```

I need to select those raws, where the *number* is by 10 or more bigger than the previous one of the same *color*.

So for example:

```
color number
black 1
blue 2
black 6
black 20
black 21
blue 22
blue 23
```

should return:

```
black 20
blue 22
```

Please, could you suggest me how to write such a query in SQLite? Or at least give me some hints on how to think about the problem?

Comment: Is there another column (like an id) that denotes the order of the rows?

Comment: No, I have only sorted table of two columns according to the number.

Comment: Then it is the column `number` that denotes the order?

Comment: Yes, the `number` denotes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()` window function to check the previous number of the same color for each row:

```
SELECT color, number
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(number) OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY number) prev_number
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE number - prev_number > 10;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f6eea43ec93eb2b2d2a877e2b6b15de1).